# Plugging a USB wifi adapter into a physical hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, wireless-networking, usb, adapter

I'm thinking of getting a USB wifi adapter to plug into a desktop PC hard drive (manufactured by Dell) to access my xfinity wifi hot wire.

Is it possible to plug such a device into a hard drive? If so, would I plug it into the back or the front?

Comment: Do you mean plugging in the Wifi adapter to a port on the computer, or are you specifically trying to plug in a wifi adapater to a hard drive? (hard drives are used to store data, not process it or host other devices)

Answer (score 1):

No. It is possible to get external hard drives that have built-in WIFI and media server capabilities, but obviously you would know if you had one of those.

In general, to make a drive available on the network, you must host the drive on a network-enabled server of some kind. This could be your PC, a Raspberry PI, or almost any other kind of computer.

As an alternative to using a computer to host the drive, you may host it on a dedicated adapter such as [this one](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Verbatim-98243-MediaShare-Wireless/dp/B00CZ0P0PS/ref=psdc_430544031_t1_B00J3HMY1E).

Some routers and WIFI extenders are equipped with a USB media port, so if you are thinking of replacing your router or getting an extender anyway, this is another option and would avoid having to purchase a separate adapter.

Comment: I believe the asker was using the term "hard drive" when they meant to say "PC". A somewhat common misnomer for the older and less tech-savvy population

Comment: @SamForbis I think you are correct here.